# Trying to set jacoco-check code coverage on submodule

Tags: java, maven, jacoco

I have some submodules in my application. Some I wish to have code coverage rules and some I wish to exempt completely.

My project's root POM inherits from a parent POM which has JaCoCo configured as so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>${jacoco-maven-plugin.version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <fileSets>
            <fileSet>
                <directory>domain/target</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.exec</include>
                </includes>
            </fileSet>
            <fileSet>
                <directory>integration/target</directory>
                <includes>
                    <include>*.exec</include>
                </includes>
            </fileSet>
        </fileSets>
        <destFile>target/jacoco.exec</destFile>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

In a submodule, `test`, in which I wish to have 50% code coverage I have configured JaCoCo as so:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-check</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <rule>
                        <element>PACKAGE</element>
                        <limits>
                            <limit>
                                <counter>LINE</counter>
                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                <minimum>0.5</minimum>
                            </limit>
                        </limits>
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

This module has absolutely zero code coverage but running `mvn clean verify` does not produce any error.

I figured that maybe I had to define it in the root POM, so I did this as:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-prepare-agent</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>jacoco-check</id>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <rules>
                    <rule>
                        <element>PACKAGE</element>
                        <limits>
                            <limit>
                                <counter>LINE</counter>
                                <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                <minimum>0.75</minimum>
                            </limit>
                        </limits>
                    </rule>
                </rules>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

`mvn clean verify` does produce an error:

> [WARNING] Rule violated for package com.project: lines covered ratio is 0.00, but expected minimum is 0.75

The problem is, I want a blanket value of 0.75 for my other submodules but for this module, `test` I want a value of 0.5. I found [this link](http://maven.apache.org/pom.html#:%7E:text=%3C/plugin%3E-,advanced%20configuration%20inheritance,-%3A%20combine.children%20and) that described inheritance and `combine.self="override"`. So I added this to the configuration options in `test`:

```
<execution>
    <id>jacoco-check</id>
    <goals>
        <goal>check</goal>
    </goals>
    <configuration combine.self="override">
        <rules>
            <rule>
                <element>PACKAGE</element>
                <limits>
                    <limit>
                        <counter>LINE</counter>
                        <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                        <minimum>0.5</minimum>
                    </limit>
                </limits>
            </rule>
        </rules>
    </configuration>
</execution>
```

Despite this override, I still get the error complaining it expects 0.75 when I want 0.5:

> [WARNING] Rule violated for package com.project: lines covered ratio is 0.00, but expected minimum is 0.75

How can I override this in the submodule?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution to this was to use `<pluginManagement>` in the POM in the root of the project, and then manually declare the code coverage in each submodule.

**Root POM:**

```
    <build>
        <pluginManagement>
            <plugins>
                <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                    <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                    <executions>
                        <execution>
                            <goals>
                                <goal>prepare-agent</goal>
                            </goals>
                        </execution>
                    </executions>
                </plugin>
            </plugins>
        </pluginManagement>
    </build>
```

**A Submodule POM where I desired 0 code coverage:**

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.jacoco</groupId>
                <artifactId>jacoco-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>test</id>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>check</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <rules>
                                <rule>
                                    <element>BUNDLE</element>
                                    <limits>
                                        <limit>
                                            <counter>LINE</counter>
                                            <value>COVEREDRATIO</value>
                                            <minimum>0</minimum>
                                        </limit>
                                    </limits>
                                </rule>
                            </rules>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```